# issue with restricting RDS rds:ModifyDBInstance by tags in iam policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created an DB IAM policy as show below that restricts users to allow only startDBInstance, StopDBInstance and ModifyDBInstance on specific database but ModifyDBInstance does not seem to be working. Please let me if my policy is correct or do I need to change anything?

DB IAM Policy:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"AllowDevTestCreate",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "rds:ModifyDBInstance"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"allow start & stop",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "rds:StartDBInstance",
            "rds:StopDBInstance",
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:*:db:*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"Deny all expect the tag condition",
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Action":[
            "rds:*"
         ],
         "Resource":"*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringNotEquals":{
               "rds:db-tag/app name":[
                  "test1",
                  "test2"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected:
user can only start, stop and modify the db instances with specified tags only

Actual:
1. User is able to start and stop DB instance
2. Implicit permission denied on ModifyDBInstance even though my DB the app name matched

Comment: Why do you have a `deny` permission?

Comment: Since its a data base, I wanted to make sure everything is explicitly denied and allow only permissions that user need.

Comment: explicit deny will takeover precedence over allow. If you have both allow and deny for a particular action IAM will consider this as deny.

Answer (score 0):

Your allowed action is being overridden by the explicit deny. You don't need to specify the deny action since IAM has an implicit deny feature. Which means, any action which doesn't have either of the deny or allow explicitly provided are denied by default.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"AllowDevTestCreate",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "rds:ModifyDBInstance"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"allow start & stop",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "rds:StartDBInstance",
            "rds:StopDBInstance",
         ],
         "Resource":"*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "rds:db-tag/app name":[
                  "test1",
                  "test2"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm not sure if `ModifyInstance` supports resource tags. If yes, you can merge the first statement to the second one.